# JSOUP parse iframe Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, iframe, jsoup

I am trying to parse the latitude and longitude from the Google Maps map on this website http://hdh.ucsd.edu/mobile/dining/locationmap.aspx?l=39 but I am unable to fetch anything. How would I be able to get the latitude and longitude? Or what query would be able to accomplish this?

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements elements = document.select("div.place-name");
String LOCATION = elements.text();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the coordinates from the `src` attribute of the `iframe` tag. That URL contains the `q` parameter that will give you the coordinates separated by comma.

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow34038430;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

/**
 * Stackoverflow 34038430 question.
 *
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://hdh.ucsd.edu/mobile/dining/locationmap.aspx?l=39";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        String src = document.select("iframe").first().attr("src");
        URL srcUrl = new URL(src);
        String result = getParamValue(srcUrl.getQuery());
        String[] coordinates = result.split(",");
        Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
        System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude);
        System.out.println("Longitude: " + longitude);
    }

    /**
     * Get the param value.
     * @param query The query string.
     * @return Returns the parameter value.
     */
    public static String getParamValue(String query) {
        String[] params = query.split("&");
        for (String param : params) {
            String name = param.split("=")[0];
            if("q".equals(name)){
                return param.split("=")[1];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This url that you provided does not have `div.place-name` because it is in iframe if you inspect it with firebug.

It is harder to get coordinates because this [URL](http://maps.google.com/?f=d&source=s_d&layer=tc&hl=en&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&q=32.881093211,-117.2406307&z=15&output=embed) must be used in iframe.

Iframe tag has src tag that has coordinates. If those are cooridnates `q=32.881093211,-117.2406307` you can get the iframe with JSOUP and extract these two numbers with custom regex.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10411996)

Comment: I have told that mentioned url that has coordinates but I did not mention that is is src tag. So extracting them is pretty straightforward. It can be even tested here : http://try.jsoup.org/ for mentioned url.